# Admob Ad's during Development

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, admob

My doubt is not weather its ok to click on live ads during development.I did all the formalities to get my admob ad working . Then i saw that we should only use test add during development . so i used this code:

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
.addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // An example device ID
.build();
```

It worked fine. But then i change i back to the live ad code fearing that i would forget to do so later:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But now the ad wont appear during test run. Is that normal?

will the ad work when i finally launch the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see anything wrong with your code, but something similar happened to me when implementing admob too.

I didnt have in count that the ad must be loaded before showing it, and that the loading may take some time. If you try to show an ad that its not loaded, a black activity might be shown.

You should implement some waiting time or a listener in order to be sure that the add is loaded before showing it.

```
public InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
[...]
public void setNewInterstitialRequest()
{
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(CurrActivity.this);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-***************************");

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        //.addTestDevice("ZY22247DJV")
        .build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

    //add listener so you know is fully loaded
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            [...]  // <- code you want to execute as soon as the ad is loaded
        }
    });
}
public void displayAd() {
    try {
        //verify is loaded before showing a black screen
        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            interstitialAd.show();
        }
        //else
        //  showToast("Not loaded");
    }
    catch (Exception ex){}
}
```

So taking this in mind, if you want for the ad to be shown inmediately when something happens, you should have it loaded before that event occurs.